# list column group by and summarise

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

**AIM:** I would like to write the following code that works fine on a data frame, but for each of the data frames of a list column work flow.

Notice that I take the first element of the list and create a data frame and then work with that data frame because I haven't figured out how to `group_by` nested lists (see HAVE TRIED).

**[DATA](https://www.kaggle.com/sebastianmantey/nba-free-throws/home)**

**CURRENTLY WORKING:**

```html
nested_NBA <- NBA%>%
  group_by(season)%>%
  nest()
 
one_season <- nested_NBA$data[1]

one_season%>% 
  bind_rows()%>%
  group_by(player)%>%
  summarise(shots_attempts_ratio=sum(shot_made)/n(),
            total_attempts=n(),
            shots=sum(shot_made))
```

**HAVE TRIED:**

`nested_NBA%>%
 map(data, ~group_by(.x$player))`

**ERROR:**

```html
Warning messages:
1: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : data set ‘.x[[i]]’ not found
2: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : data set ‘~group_by(.x$player)’ not found
3: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : data set ‘.x[[i]]’ not found
4: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : data set ‘~group_by(.x$player)’ not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `nest` step, we can loop through the 'data' `list` within `mutate` using `map`, then do the `group_by` and `summarise` with it

```
library(tidyverse)
NBA%>%
  group_by(season)%>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
        group_by(player)%>%
        summarise(shots_attempts_ratio=sum(shot_made)/n(),
        total_attempts=n(),
        shots=sum(shot_made))
        )) %>%
 unnest
```

Comment: @delcast Yes, you were close.  The issue was in extracting the column value instead of specifying the identifier  for the column in `group_by`